# Замена страницы New Tab/ Новая вкладка

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Как заменить cтраницу открывающуюся при нажатии на кнопку `New Tab`/ `Новая вкладка`, которая так же доступна по адресу `chrome://newtab`?

[image: Кнопка "Новая вкладка" в Google Chrome]

Comment: *Помогите, меня никто не понимает. Как встать Солнце на востоке?*

Comment: Все-таки вам нужно было заменить страницу "новая вкладка" - а не открыть ее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё разобрался, почитал подробнее про manifest.json. Нужно было добавить в manifest

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
  "newtab": "main.html"
},
```